# The authorize() method of react-native-app-auth gives a 404

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to authenticate a user in my react-native app using an external service with the package `react-native-app-auth`
I have this code snippet:

```
import { authorize } from 'react-native-app-auth';

const config = {
 issuer: `https://api.ex.fr/oauth/authorize`,
 clientId: `30480b7aaaaaaa0212be3`,
 redirectUrl: `com.cluster42://redirect`,
 scopes: ['public'],
};

const redirectToBrowser = async () => {
 try {
   await authorize(config);
 } catch (error) {
   console.log('error==', error)
 }
}
```

After triggering the method `redirectToBrowser()`, I get this error from the catch block (executed on iOS):

```
error== [Error: Non-200 HTTP response (404) fetching discovery document 'https://api.ex.fr/oauth/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration'.]
```

I also don't know from where is this link coming:
`https://api.ex.fr/oauth/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration`

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.71.8
react-native-app-auth: "^7.0.0"